# PHP PDO Security Procedures for Simple Inserting into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo, sql-injection

I'm just starting to learn PHP (alongside SQL) and I've looked a lot into security measures. This website: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet 
has helped me, although most of it is admittedly lost to a beginner like me.

I've found that to prevent an SQL injection the best way to proceed is through prepared and parameterized queries. So I've written my PHP code in PDO.

But I still feel like its not all that secure, especially because I am handling file transfer.

I would appreciate it if any one could look at the methodology of my code to see if there is any immediate security issues with it.

Thanks :)

```
<?php $servername = "localhost";
$username = "hello";
$password = "world";
$dbname = "file_uploads";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, 
$password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// prepare sql and bind parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO file_uploads (file, name) VALUES (:file, 
:name");

$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name); 
$stmt->bindParam(':file', $file); 

// from data in an html form
$name=$_POST['name'];
$file=$_POST['file'];

$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Don't you get an undefined variable notice?  You declare the file and name variable after you bind parameter

Comment: where does `$dbConnection` come from?

Comment: Also see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/608639)

Comment: I don't for one reason or another. $dbConnection is an error in the code, that should be just $conn.

Answer (score 0):

> But I still feel like its not all that secure, especially because I am handling file transfer.

So, there are two issues being concerned with right now:

- Are prepared statements enough to stop SQL injection?

  - Yes, as long as you disable EMULATE_PREPARES.
  - See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202218/2224584) for more information.
  - Libraries such as [EasyDB](https://github.com/paragonie/easydb) provide more secure defaults than PDO. ([For example](https://github.com/paragonie/easydb/blob/76094ff093d6a3ee1ab3a9a6fc133cb6dbd54327/src/EasyDB.php#L47-L55).)
- Is this a safe way to upload files?

  - The code is broken in many ways, but nothing directly security-related jumps out at me.
  - See [this guide](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/10/how-securely-allow-users-upload-files) for handling file uploads. Note that you'll want to use `$_FILES` not `$_POST` to process uploaded files.